# Contains en consulta LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

teniendo una consulta que busca por títulos de películas en una base de datos, quiero sacar las que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda introducido mediante un `input` de tipo `text`. Para ello uso un `Contains` con la variable `busqueda` que almacena dicho patrón.

```
 var peliculaConsulta = from Peliculas in dbDatos.Peliculas
                                   join TipoPelicula in dbDatos.TipoPelicula
                                    on Peliculas.idTipo equals TipoPelicula.IdTipo
                                   where Peliculas.Titulo.Contains(busqueda)
                                   select new { Peliculas.Titulo, Peliculas.TipoPelicula, TipoPelicula.Tipo };


                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Título</th>
                            <th>País</th>
                            <th>Tipo de película</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>

            foreach (var elemento in peliculaConsulta)
            {
                    <td>@elemento.Titulo</td><td>@elemento.TipoPelicula</td><td>@elemento.Tipo</td>


            }
```

Al presentarlo por pantalla me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que LINQ se esta haciendo un lío bastante grande con los alias que has puesto en los join ya que TipoPelicula es una propiedad de la entidad Peliculas y ademas es una entidad propia Peliculas, por "soft linq" películas también tiene incluida la entidad "TipoPelicula" incluidas por tener una FK, revísate los alias y pon por ejemplo la linea `join TP in dbDatos.TipoPelicula` y conrrige la query en consecuencia, eso debería hacer que sacara bien el dato (ahora mismo esta sacando la expresión linq de la tabla TipoPelicula entidad asociado a Pelicula)

Un saludo